# How to deal with Censored instances?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, survival, scikit-survival

I am working on a project to predict day to an event(graft failure) using machine learning approaches with a dataset containing about 900 variables, I am new to this area and I am not sure whether I am in the right track.

At first, I used Neural Network for prediction using Keras library in python, then I figured out I have 70% censored instances in my data (Y variable). However, I have also a follow up variable in addition to the Y. So, I came to conclusion that I should not use Neural Network for this kind of problems and also I have to handle censored data beforehand. Now I have three questions:

1) Is it normal to have this rate of censored data? How should we deal with this kind of cases?

2) Is my conclusion correct that Neural Network is not the best solution for my problem? If not, what is the most common machine learning approach? I've found lifelines and scikit-survival packages for this purpose, but I don't know which one is better and It is the right solution.

3) I replaced censored data with follow up variable, while according to the high percentage of censoring data in my dataset I think it is not suitable. I realized that I should use another approach like Calibration, but I could not find out the python library for doing this. Could you please help me with this? What usually is used for Calibration in Pyhton?

Comment: Hey I was curious what you decided to do. To answer your question, the only want to deal with censored data I think is to use a model that predicts cox proportional hazard/kaplan meier like this https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-11817-6. Unfortunately, I am sure how this is exactly implemented.

Comment: Looks like there is a framework here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323409041_DeepSurv_Personalized_treatment_recommender_system_using_a_Cox_proportional_hazards_deep_neural_network. it has an associate GitHub https://github.com/jaredleekatzman/DeepSurv. Unfortunately in Theano not Keras

Comment: Hi Sarah, here is a paper that may be of use to you: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046416000496, The authors suggest many possible methods but do not explicitly mention neural networks (although Bayesian networks are mentioned). It's possible that a neural network could still be a suitable model but it's likely to require a lot of feature engineering and possibly a custom loss function.

Answer (score 0):

A way to deal with censored data I think is to use a model that predicts cox proportional hazard/kaplan meier. Looks like there is a framework here researchgate.net/publication/…. it has an associate GitHub github.com/jaredleekatzman/DeepSurv. Unfortunately in Theano not Keras

I take back what I said. I found a keras version (though I think it is still backend with theano; not too hard to change)!

https://github.com/mexchy1000/DeepSurv_Keras/blob/master/Survival_Keras_lifelineExample.py